# MySql how to union 2 queries within if statements

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, union

Here my form and the mysql/php code.

if the 2 checkboxes are both checked mysql doesn't execute the queries. **Is there any way to have this form working properly?**

**MySQL**

```
 if (isset($_POST['A']) && !empty($_POST['A'])) {
 $query= "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE...) as A WHERE Column1='y'";
 }
 if (isset($_POST['B']) && !empty($_POST['B'])) {
 $query= "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE...) as B WHERE Column2='y'";
 }
```

**Form**

```
<form id="myform1" class="myform1" method="post" name="myform1">
<input type="checkbox" name="A[]" id="A" value="y" />
<input type="checkbox" name="B[]" id="B" value="y" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" 
onclick="return submitForm1()" />
</form>
```

**Any help appreciated. Thank you**

Comment: You realize that you need to check the value of `$_POST['A'][0]` since you are using array access notation `A[]` in your input names?  You should probably remove this and just call the input fields `A` and `B` since I don't see how you need to make this an array. It just so happens that this doesn't matter in your case because you don't actually use the value of the input anywhere.  Just wanted to point his out is this could cause confusion in futrue cases where you do need such a value.

Comment: Can you show the full code?  Are you actually querying the database within the conditionals but are just not showing it, or is MySQL query actually take place using `$query` after both conditionals have been executed (in which case only the query from the last successful conditional would be run)?

Comment: Hi @Mark thank u for your comment. I appreciate your advice but var_dump returns that values are parsed right. My problem is how to union the 2 queries the

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the full queries.  I am not sure that a union is really even needed, but have no idea since you haven't shown the subselect.  I honestly don't even know if you need the subselect.

Comment: Ok I will post all queries as soon as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, its ugly but simple :

```
$teamsters = ''; 
$query = '';
if (isset($_POST['A'][0]) && !empty($_POST['A'][0])) {
   $query= "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE...) as A WHERE Column1='y'";
   $teamsters = ' UNION ';
}
if (isset($_POST['B'][0]) && !empty($_POST['B'][0])) {
   $query .= $teamsters . "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE...) as B WHERE Column2='y'";
}
```